# How to load image in jquery mobile dynamically

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I want to change img tag source when page has loaded (new src will come from ajax request) .I use this jquery mobile code but it doesn't work :

```
<div class="col-md-12 shop_logo_div" id="shop_logo_div"></div>
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#EditProfileRootPage', function () {
var img = $('<img />').attr({
            'id': 'shop_logo',
            'src': UserMeta.logo_url,
            'width': 250
        }).appendTo('#shop_logo_div');
});
```

I changed pagecreate event to pageinit or  pagebeforecreate or pagebeforeshow but  nothing has changed.

---

I had this error and I didn't see it :

> Refused to load the image
>   'http://localhost/shop/wp-content/plugins/amir-shopping-system/upload/1532819683.png'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'".
>   Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used
>   as a fallback.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *;img-src http://localhost/shop/; connect-src 'self' http://localhost/shop/webservices/services/api.php">
```

I changed Content-Security-Policy but it still has problem.What do I have to do ?

Comment: It does not work... How? Do you receive an error message? What is the behavior you experience?

Answer (score 0):

I use this csp in my root index file and my problem has solved.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src 'self' http://localhost/shop/webservices/services/api.php;img-src *">
```